# Multiple SLF4J Bindings - log4j to logback

Tags: spring-boot, maven, logging, log4j, logback

I'm trying to convert my app from working with log4j to logback, i'm using spring boot and maven, i added logback dependencies and excluded spring-boot-starter-logging.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

But when i try to build my app, i get this error, i have multiple slf4j bindings and its also still using Log4jLoggerFactory

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Dev/repo/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.14.1/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.14.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Dev/repo/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.6/logback-classic-1.2.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

Comment: Use `mvn dependency:tree` and check which dependency is bringing the other one

Comment: thank you, i found out there is other libraries like jasckson that brings log4j